# How to change the url with rewrite rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a code

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*).php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?go=$1
```

Now when i load any other page like fault.php(which is in my directory) then the page loads without  external javascript and css

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
   RewriteEngine On

   # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
   # getting no_script_name to work
   # RewriteBase /

   # default front controller
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The client thinks you are in a different path.

Try giving a path relative to the root instead.  You can easily do this by putting a `/` in front of the paths, assuming you are relative to the root to begin with.

---

For example, if normally you access a page here:

```
/index.php
```

And, you have some code in that script like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/somescript.js"></script>
```

And, now instead of `index.php`, you use something like this:

```
/something/somethingelse
```

The client is going to try to load `/something/somethingelse/js/somescript.js`, but of course the file isn't there.  You need to specify it relative to the root, like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/somescript.js"></script>
```

Comment: See my last edit, and if that doesn't help you, ask more questions.